# Alter enum type in migration using Knex + postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, migration, knex.js

I need to add one more value to Enum type. Migration successfully finished but I don't see any result in database. Enum `prod_status` still has old values inside.

I'm using this code to make a migration.

```
exports.up = async function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.alterTable('products', (table) => {
    table.enu('status', ['hidden', 'published', 'reserved', 'sold', 'deleted', 'not-visible'], { useNative: true, enumName: 'prod_status' }).defaultTo('hidden').notNullable().index().alter();
  }).toSQL();
};

exports.down = async function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.alterTable('products', (table) => {
    table.enum('status', ['hidden', 'published', 'reserved', 'sold', 'deleted'], { useNative: true, enumName: 'prod_status' }).defaultTo('hidden').notNullable().index().alter();
  }).toSQL();
};
```

I have also tried other variants from similar quesitons [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714345/update-enum-column-types-in-knex-migration) an [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45299464/alter-table-modify-enum-in-knex-js-for-postgresql-gives-error) but getting errors.

Looking for your help and/or adnivces.

Comment: Is this typo in your code?  `table.enu('status',`

Comment: according to knex.js docs it is possible to use `enu/enum`

Comment: Try to remove the "toSql" call, it is redundant

Comment: without `.toSQL()` getting an error that this type already exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mikael Lepistö proposed to use `.raw` and it was really only possible way to solve it.
My working solution:

```
exports.up = async function(knex) {
  return knex.raw(`
    CREATE TYPE prod_status_temp AS ENUM ('hidden', 'published', 'reserved', 'sold', 'deleted', 'not-visible');
    ALTER TABLE products
      ALTER COLUMN status DROP DEFAULT,
      ALTER COLUMN status TYPE prod_status_temp USING status::text::prod_status_temp;
    DROP TYPE IF EXISTS prod_status;
    ALTER TYPE prod_status_temp RENAME TO prod_status;
  `);
};

exports.down = async function(knex) {
  return knex.raw(`
    CREATE TYPE prod_status_temp AS ENUM ('hidden', 'published', 'reserved', 'sold', 'deleted');
    ALTER TABLE products
      ALTER COLUMN status DROP DEFAULT,
      ALTER COLUMN status TYPE prod_status_temp USING status::text::prod_status_temp;
    DROP TYPE IF EXISTS prod_status;
    ALTER TYPE prod_status_temp RENAME TO prod_status;
  `);
};
```

Hope it helps somebody in future.

Comment: ```table.enum("event_type", ["created", "updated"], { useNative: true, enumName: "event_type" });```

For my specific case where I wanted to add "deleted" to enum, and this is the only solution that work with knex 0.21.1 and pg 7.4.3. Note how I have named my own type `event_type`

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you need to use `knex.schema.raw` for this. `.alter()` doesn't really work with native enums.